# Gatsby JS - Generating SSR bundle failed

Tags: internet-explorer, gatsby

I have a problem making Gatsby to work under IE11 on development mode.
When I execute **npm start** I get the following error:

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating SSR bundle failed

.cache\develop-static-entry.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (31:10)

  29 | export default (pagePath, callback) => {
  30 |   let headComponents = [
> 31 |     <meta key="environment" name="note" content="environment=development" />,
     |           ^
  32 |   ]
  33 |   let htmlAttributes = {}
  34 |   let bodyAttributes = {}

File: .cache\develop-static-entry.js:31:10
```

This is how looks my .babelrc file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-object-super"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-classes"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"]
  ],
  "presets": [["babel-preset-gatsby-package"]]
}
```

This is version of gatsby-cli

```
"gatsby-cli": "^2.12.99",
```

I tried many thins but was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Have you [specify the browserlist](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/browser-support/#specify-what-browsers-your-project-supports-using-browserslist) in `package.json`? I found a similar thread: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21664, you can refer to the solutions in it. It seems that deleting `package-lock.json` file can help.

Answer (score 1):

It's an extremely broad question and lacks of trials. IE fallback could fail from infinite reasons and pieces of code. Among trying to debug some offending code for IE11, try adding the following snippet in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-object-super"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-classes"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"]
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 2
      }
    ],
    [
      "babel-preset-gatsby",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            ">0.25%",
            "not dead"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
}
```

It seems that you are missing some Babel presets to Gatsby:

- [`babel-preset-gatsby`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-gatsby)
- [`babel-preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env): this may not be required, omit it if the compilation fails.
- [`babel-preset-gatsby-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-gatsby-package): seems a deprecated dependency in favor of `babel-preset-gatsby`, remove it if it causes issues.

Install them via `npm` or `yarn` and use them.

Alternatively, you can try adding the following snippet to your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = function onCreateWebpackConfig({ actions, stage, loaders }) {
  if (stage === 'develop') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-hot-loader/,
            use: [
              loaders.js()
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14502 (you can follow the other workarounds)

Comment: After installing these plugins and changing .babelrc the problem remains exactly the same.

Comment: I would suggest this thread: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14502 try some of the workarounds

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately already tried.